# Symfony incompatibilities. The LoaderInterface and the XmlFileLoader have an issue

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php, tiki-wiki

Situation:
This is the screen message I became after installing tikiwiki 24.

> Fatal error: Declaration of Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Loader\XmlFileLoader::load($resource, ?string $type = NULL) must be compatible with Symfony\Component\Config\Loader\LoaderInterface::load($resource, $type = NULL) in /var/www/contiki/vendor/symfony/dependency-injection/Loader/XmlFileLoader.php on line 46

So please, does anyone have a clue what's going on here? I'm quite new to composer, solved many compatibility issues but this is out of my range.

I don't understand why they are incompatible.

These are (part) of the files:

My /var/www/contiki/vendor_bundled/vendor/symfony/config/Loader/LoaderInterface.php

```
interface LoaderInterface
{
    /**
     * Loads a resource.
     *
     * @param mixed       $resource The resource
     * @param string|null $type     The resource type or null if unknown
     *
     * @throws \Exception If something went wrong
     */
    public function load($resource, $type = null);

    /**
     * Returns whether this class supports the given resource.
     *
     * @param mixed       $resource A resource
     * @param string|null $type     The resource type or null if unknown
     *
     * @return bool True if this class supports the given resource, false otherwise
     */
    public function supports($resource, $type = null);

    /**
     * Gets the loader resolver.
     *
     * @return LoaderResolverInterface A LoaderResolverInterface instance
     */
    public function getResolver();

    /**
     * Sets the loader resolver.
     */
    public function setResolver(LoaderResolverInterface $resolver);
}
```

The first part of the /var/www/contiki/vendor_bundled/vendor/symfony/dependency-injection/Loader/XmlFileLoader.php file

````
namespace Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Loader;

use Symfony\Component\Config\Util\XmlUtils;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Alias;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Argument\BoundArgument;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Argument\IteratorArgument;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Argument\TaggedIteratorArgument;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ChildDefinition;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Definition;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\InvalidArgumentException;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\RuntimeException;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Reference;
use Symfony\Component\ExpressionLanguage\Expression;

/**
 * XmlFileLoader loads XML files service definitions.
 *
 * @author Fabien Potencier <fabien@symfony.com>
 */
class XmlFileLoader extends FileLoader
{
    const NS = 'http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services';

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function load($resource, $type = null)
    {
        $path = $this->locator->locate($resource);

        $xml = $this->parseFileToDOM($path);

        $this->container->fileExists($path);  <-- This is rule 46

        $defaults = $this->getServiceDefaults($xml, $path);

        // anonymous services
        $this->processAnonymousServices($xml, $path, $defaults);

        // imports
        $this->parseImports($xml, $path);

        // parameters
        $this->parseParameters($xml, $path);

        // extensions
        $this->loadFromExtensions($xml);

        // services
        try {
            $this->parseDefinitions($xml, $path, $defaults);
        } finally {
            $this->instanceof = [];
        }
    }```
````

Comment: Please share more details. Which versions of these packages (namely: `symfony/dependency-injection` and `symfony/config`) do you use?

Comment: Also, which version of PHP do you use?

Comment: Also, according to https://sourceforge.net/projects/tikiwiki/files/, there is no version 24 of TikiWiki yet

Comment: smarty/smarty                    v4.0.3
symfony/dependency-injection     v5.4.2
symfony/config                   v5.4.2

PHP 7.4.3 (cli) (built: Nov 25 2021 23:16:22)
I used the files from Github: git clone https://gitlab.com/tikiwiki/tiki.git its the master version. Guessed it would be version 24, but you're right its a late 23.x
 After reading your reply I installed symfony/config and reran the setup. Now I have a different error:

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it. Also, if you are facing errors after installing the software, without modifying it, please report this to the project's bug tracker. StackOverflow won't provide general support for other software

Comment: Guess it's an other problem, so I will make a new Question.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like something's got tangled up here, Tiki 24 is not out yet but will be branching soon, so if you want a stable safe Tiki now, probably best to use a stable released branch, i.e. [23.x](https://gitlab.com/tikiwiki/tiki/-/tree/23.x)? Also, we are still on Smarty 3.x and plan to upgrade to 4.x (and PHP 8+) after the release of 24 which is our next LTS version, so not sure where that is coming from... did you run `sh setup.sh`?

As Nico said above, this is probably more Tiki-specific than is suitable for here, so the best thing would be to come and chat with the community in our new Gitter room, [here](https://gitter.im/tiki-org/community)?

Welcome to Tiki! :)